# How to set .env variable for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a ReactJS application and I want to deploy to 3 production environments: production1, production2 and production3.

I have env files as: .env (for development), .env.production1 (production 1), .env.production2 (production2) and .env.production3 (production3).

I run the systax 'npm start' but it reads variables from file .env.

Is there any way to run 'npm start' with specific .env file?

Something like:

```
npm start (read from .env file)
npm start .env.production1 (read from .env.prod1 file)
npm start .env.production2 (read from .env.prod2 file)
npm start .env.production3 (read from .env.prod3 file)
```

I read a reference here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables but this is for 'development', 'test' and 'production'. My case is production but for 3 environments.

This is the problem which I have during deployment the production to the client.
If anyone down-votes this, please tell me why?

Thank you.

Comment: I think https://dev.to/jam3/managing-env-variables-for-provisional-builds-h37 will help you.

Comment: From the link above, npm start will pick up .env.development, and npm build will use environment variables in .env.production. I know it but my question is production for 3 environments.

Comment: Have you seen how author has added `build:staging`. You can do it for your different production environment

Comment: Added build:staging, but how to use it? Run 'npm build:staging', doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

you need four .env file

```
.env
.env.production1
.env.production2
.env.production3
```

Then read form .env using

```
let mode = process.env.NODE_ENV
```

which could be production1 or production2 or production3

then use mode to get other configuration data like

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `/path/to/.env.${mode}` })
```

when you need to switch between configuration then just modify .env like below

```
NODE_ENV = production1
```

or

```
NODE_ENV = production2
```

or

```
NODE_ENV = production3
```

Comment: process.env.NODE_ENV is either development, test or production but this is productions for 3 environments: env.production1, env.production2 and env.production3. How do you deal with it? My question is there is any syntax like 'npm start .env.production1'?

Comment: You can try my answer now